# How to change currency format in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, price, currency, locale

Currently, the price shows like $2.999,00

I want the price to show like $2,999.00 for locale es_MX (Spanish, Mexico) in **product pages**, anywhere else the currency format is correct.

**I've tried all solutions in StackExchange but no one works.**

File app/code/Jsp/Currency/etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Locale\Format" type="Jsp\Currency\Model\Format"/>
</config>
```

File app/code/Jsp/Currency/Model/Format.php

```
<?php
namespace Jsp\Currency\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Locale\Bundle\DataBundle;

class Format extends \Magento\Framework\Locale\Format
{
    private static $defaultNumberSet = 'latn';

    public function getPriceFormat($localeCode = null, $currencyCode = null)
    {
        $localeCode = $localeCode ?: $this->_localeResolver->getLocale();
        if ($currencyCode) {
            $currency = $this->currencyFactory->create()->load($currencyCode);
        } else {
            $currency = $this->_scopeResolver->getScope()->getCurrentCurrency();
        }

        $localeData = (new DataBundle())->get($localeCode);
        $defaultSet = $localeData['NumberElements']['default'] ?: self::$defaultNumberSet;

        $format = $localeData['NumberElements'][$defaultSet]['patterns']['currencyFormat']
            ?: ($localeData['NumberElements'][self::$defaultNumberSet]['patterns']['currencyFormat']
                ?: explode(';', $localeData['NumberPatterns'][1])[0]);

        //your main changes are gone here.....
        if($localeCode == 'es_MX'){
            $decimalSymbol = '.';
            $groupSymbol = ',';
        }else{
            $decimalSymbol = $localeData['NumberElements'][$defaultSet]['symbols']['decimal']
                ?: ($localeData['NumberElements'][self::$defaultNumberSet]['symbols']['decimal']
                    ?: $localeData['NumberElements'][0]);

            $groupSymbol = $localeData['NumberElements'][$defaultSet]['symbols']['group']
                ?: ($localeData['NumberElements'][self::$defaultNumberSet]['symbols']['group']
                    ?: $localeData['NumberElements'][1]);
        }

        $pos = strpos($format, ';');
        if ($pos !== false) {
            $format = substr($format, 0, $pos);
        }
        $format = preg_replace("/[^0\#\.,]/", "", $format);
        $totalPrecision = 0;
        $decimalPoint = strpos($format, '.');
        if ($decimalPoint !== false) {
            $totalPrecision = strlen($format) - (strrpos($format, '.') + 1);
        } else {
            $decimalPoint = strlen($format);
        }
        $requiredPrecision = $totalPrecision;
        $t = substr($format, $decimalPoint);
        $pos = strpos($t, '#');
        if ($pos !== false) {
            $requiredPrecision = strlen($t) - $pos - $totalPrecision;
        }

        if (strrpos($format, ',') !== false) {
            $group = $decimalPoint - strrpos($format, ',') - 1;
        } else {
            $group = strrpos($format, '.');
        }
        $integerRequired = strpos($format, '.') - strpos($format, '0');

        $result = [
            //TODO: change interface
            'pattern' => $currency->getOutputFormat(),
            'precision' => $totalPrecision,
            'requiredPrecision' => $requiredPrecision,
            'decimalSymbol' => $decimalSymbol,
            'groupSymbol' => $groupSymbol,
            'groupLength' => $group,
            'integerRequired' => $integerRequired,
        ];       
        return $result;
    }
}
```

File vendor/magento/framework/Locale/Format.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Framework\Locale;

use Magento\Framework\Locale\Bundle\DataBundle;

class Format implements \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private static $defaultNumberSet = 'latn';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ScopeResolverInterface
     */
    protected $_scopeResolver;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface
     */
    protected $_localeResolver;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory
     */
    protected $currencyFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ScopeResolverInterface $scopeResolver
     * @param ResolverInterface $localeResolver
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ScopeResolverInterface $scopeResolver,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory
    ) {
        $this->_scopeResolver = $scopeResolver;
        $this->_localeResolver = $localeResolver;
        $this->currencyFactory = $currencyFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the first found number from a string
     * Parsing depends on given locale (grouping and decimal)
     *
     * Examples for input:
     * '  2345.4356,1234' = 23455456.1234
     * '+23,3452.123' = 233452.123
     * ' 12343 ' = 12343
     * '-9456km' = -9456
     * '0' = 0
     * '2 054,10' = 2054.1
     * '2'054.52' = 2054.52
     * '2,46 GB' = 2.46
     *
     * @param string|float|int $value
     * @return float|null
     */
    public function getNumber($value)
    {
        if ($value === null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!is_string($value)) {
            return floatval($value);
        }

        //trim spaces and apostrophes
        $value = str_replace(['\'', ' '], '', $value);

        $separatorComa = strpos($value, ',');
        $separatorDot = strpos($value, '.');

        if ($separatorComa !== false && $separatorDot !== false) {
            if ($separatorComa > $separatorDot) {
                $value = str_replace('.', '', $value);
                $value = str_replace(',', '.', $value);
            } else {
                $value = str_replace(',', '', $value);
            }
        } elseif ($separatorComa !== false) {
            $value = str_replace(',', '.', $value);
        }

        return floatval($value);
    }

    /**
     * Functions returns an array with price formatting info
     *
     * @param string $localeCode Locale code.
     * @param string $currencyCode Currency code.
     * @return array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    public function getPriceFormat($localeCode = null, $currencyCode = null)
    {
        $localeCode = $localeCode ?: $this->_localeResolver->getLocale();
        if ($currencyCode) {
            $currency = $this->currencyFactory->create()->load($currencyCode);
        } else {
            $currency = $this->_scopeResolver->getScope()->getCurrentCurrency();
        }
        $localeData = (new DataBundle())->get($localeCode);
        $defaultSet = $localeData['NumberElements']['default'] ?: self::$defaultNumberSet;
        $format = $localeData['NumberElements'][$defaultSet]['patterns']['currencyFormat']
            ?: ($localeData['NumberElements'][self::$defaultNumberSet]['patterns']['currencyFormat']
                ?: explode(';', $localeData['NumberPatterns'][1])[0]);

        $decimalSymbol = $localeData['NumberElements'][$defaultSet]['symbols']['decimal']
            ?: ($localeData['NumberElements'][self::$defaultNumberSet]['symbols']['decimal']
                ?: $localeData['NumberElements'][0]);

        $groupSymbol = $localeData['NumberElements'][$defaultSet]['symbols']['group']
            ?: ($localeData['NumberElements'][self::$defaultNumberSet]['symbols']['group']
                ?: $localeData['NumberElements'][1]);

        $pos = strpos($format, ';');
        if ($pos !== false) {
            $format = substr($format, 0, $pos);
        }
        $format = preg_replace("/[^0\#\.,]/", "", $format);
        $totalPrecision = 0;
        $decimalPoint = strpos($format, '.');
        if ($decimalPoint !== false) {
            $totalPrecision = strlen($format) - (strrpos($format, '.') + 1);
        } else {
            $decimalPoint = strlen($format);
        }
        $requiredPrecision = $totalPrecision;
        $t = substr($format, $decimalPoint);
        $pos = strpos($t, '#');
        if ($pos !== false) {
            $requiredPrecision = strlen($t) - $pos - $totalPrecision;
        }

        if (strrpos($format, ',') !== false) {
            $group = $decimalPoint - strrpos($format, ',') - 1;
        } else {
            $group = strrpos($format, '.');
        }
        $integerRequired = strpos($format, '.') - strpos($format, '0');

        $result = [
            //TODO: change interface
            'pattern' => $currency->getOutputFormat(),
            'precision' => $totalPrecision,
            'requiredPrecision' => $requiredPrecision,
            'decimalSymbol' => $decimalSymbol,
            'groupSymbol' => $groupSymbol,
            'groupLength' => $group,
            'integerRequired' => $integerRequired,
        ];

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check updated answer and if you have any problem let me know, This is working code for your issue. I have same issue coming for spanish site and solved using below code. Thanks.

Comment: Remove conditions in your code and just keep $decimalSymbol = '.' And $groupSymbol = ',' remove var and check. For more info i have keep updated code. Please check it.

Comment: Please check your custom module function is called or not, you can debug above function if your code is coming in getPriceFormat function or not. Cause code is working for me for same type of issue faced with me.

Comment: I noticed the Format.php file your provided is a little bit different from the one you provided. Can this be the issue? In regards to debuging the function, can you explain in more detail how can I debug it?

Comment: Do I need to add a registration.php file inside my module folder?

Comment: You have to create registration.php file and etc/module.xml file for module declaration and run php bin/magento setup:upgrade command.

Comment: You have to create module for overriding core file, so you had miss registration. Php file and module.xml file so your code is not working. Please create both file and run upgrade and deploy command. You have to just keep my code in format.php file

Comment: I try you code, but this file is not used when we use this function `$this->pricingHelper->currency($price, true, false);`. Do you know how to do the similar change ?

Comment: Will this work with cart and checkout also?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

create just simple module and overrider default *Format.php** file,

**app/code/Package/Modulename/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Locale\Format" type="Vendor\Currency\Model\Format" />
</config>
```

create model file,
**app/code/Package/Modulename/Model/Format.php**

```
<?php
namespace Package\Modulename\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Locale\Bundle\DataBundle;

class Format extends \Magento\Framework\Locale\Format
{
    private static $defaultNumberSet = 'latn';

    public function getPriceFormat($localeCode = null, $currencyCode = null)
    {
        $localeCode = $localeCode ?: $this->_localeResolver->getLocale();
        if ($currencyCode) {
            $currency = $this->currencyFactory->create()->load($currencyCode);
        } else {
            $currency = $this->_scopeResolver->getScope()->getCurrentCurrency();
        }

        $localeData = (new DataBundle())->get($localeCode);
        $defaultSet = $localeData['NumberElements']['default'] ?: self::$defaultNumberSet;

        $format = $localeData['NumberElements'][$defaultSet]['patterns']['currencyFormat']
            ?: ($localeData['NumberElements'][self::$defaultNumberSet]['patterns']['currencyFormat']
                ?: explode(';', $localeData['NumberPatterns'][1])[0]);

        //your main changes are gone here.....
        $decimalSymbol = '.';
        $groupSymbol = ',';

        $pos = strpos($format, ';');
        if ($pos !== false) {
            $format = substr($format, 0, $pos);
        }
        $format = preg_replace("/[^0\#\.,]/", "", $format);
        $totalPrecision = 0;
        $decimalPoint = strpos($format, '.');
        if ($decimalPoint !== false) {
            $totalPrecision = strlen($format) - (strrpos($format, '.') + 1);
        } else {
            $decimalPoint = strlen($format);
        }
        $requiredPrecision = $totalPrecision;
        $t = substr($format, $decimalPoint);
        $pos = strpos($t, '#');
        if ($pos !== false) {
            $requiredPrecision = strlen($t) - $pos - $totalPrecision;
        }

        if (strrpos($format, ',') !== false) {
            $group = $decimalPoint - strrpos($format, ',') - 1;
        } else {
            $group = strrpos($format, '.');
        }
        $integerRequired = strpos($format, '.') - strpos($format, '0');

        $result = [
            //TODO: change interface
            'pattern' => $currency->getOutputFormat(),
            'precision' => $totalPrecision,
            'requiredPrecision' => $requiredPrecision,
            'decimalSymbol' => $decimalSymbol,
            'groupSymbol' => $groupSymbol,
            'groupLength' => $group,
            'integerRequired' => $integerRequired,
        ];       
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I tried your solution but did not work. I updated my answer with the di.xml code I created. I also created the model file changing Package and Module name to match my folders names

Comment: I've updated my question with Format.php code. Thanks

Comment: I tried above, it works for product page but not category page, wondering!!!

Comment: its working for entire site. please check may be you have some issue;

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya, Its working for product detail page only and other prices like Totals , Cart etc. but its not working on listing page , mini cart , cart item price

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya Take a bow! Great Job!

Comment: I tried the above solution. It works only in product view page. How can I change the format in all pages??

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya: I have tried your solution but it not working on category page and cart page Item price etc.., Can any one help me to fix this issue So comma replaced by . in entire website in Arabic version.

Comment: Implemented this using a plugin, seemed to work nicely at first but then I noticed that the currency format is not updated everywhere. For example on the cart page it is updated in the totals block but not on the cart items view. Have not found a solution that actually works everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

Use below code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface')->format('999,00',true,0);
```

Format function as below:

```
public function format(
        $amount,
        $includeContainer = true,
        $precision = self::DEFAULT_PRECISION,
        $scope = null,
        $currency = null
    );
```

If  $includeContainer = true then price will show with span container

```
<span class="price">$999</span>
```

`$precision = self::DEFAULT_PRECISION` It will display two decimal point. Using 0 it will not display decimal point.

Comment: In which file should I add this code? I'm new to Magento

Comment: In which file should I add this code?

Answer (score 5):

By default of Magento 2, price format is a little strange for some currencies so we need to change it. Here’s the way to change price format.

Here’s the example for the case of Vietnamese dong.
Default displayed format was 100.000,00. Then I changed it into 100,000 (separated by comma without decimal point).

```
# vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/vi.xml
<symbols numbersystem="latn">
 <decimal>.</decimal>
 <group>,</group>
</symbols>

# vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/PriceCurrencyInterface.php
const DEFAULT_PRECISION = 0

# vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/Currency.php
return $this->formatPrecision($price, 0, $options, $includeContainer, $addBrackets);

# vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order.php
public function formatPrice($price, $addBrackets = false)
{
    return $this->formatPricePrecision($price, 0, $addBrackets);
}
```

Thanks 
Enjoy :)

Comment: tried it but does not work for es_MX

Answer (score 3):

1. Go from your root folder to vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/es_MX.xml
2. Look for `<currencyFormat`

You can set the format like this :

```
<currencyFormat type="standard">
    <pattern draft="contributed">¤#,##0.00</pattern>
</currencyFormat>
```

Comment: That format was already set like that

Answer (score 2):

to change or remove decimals for different currencies, you just need to install the free module Currency Formatter Extension from Mageplaza here the link: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-currency-formatter/.

Then you can configure the decimal for your requirement from Magento admin panel ->stores->configuration-> Mageplaza Extensions.

This worked for me in Magento 2.3.3 installation.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Bad way to do it (but faster) is hardcoding
vendor/magento/framework/Locale/Format.php

```
    $result = [
        //TODO: change interface
        'pattern' => $currency->getOutputFormat(),
        'precision' => $totalPrecision,
        'requiredPrecision' => $requiredPrecision,
        //'decimalSymbol' => $decimalSymbol,
        'decimalSymbol' =>'.',
        //'groupSymbol' => $groupSymbol,
        'groupSymbol' => ',',
        'groupLength' => $group,
        'integerRequired' => $integerRequired,
    ];
```

Comment: If it's a bad way, then why suggest it? We should _never_ modify core or vendor.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for a quick dirty solution as I want to fix a dying website while I'm working on a new version of it.