# How to remove comma separator from price in magento 2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1

How to remove comma separator from the price in magento2.1 Product List and Product page?

Answer (score 0):

to remove decimals , you just need to install the free module Currency Formatter Extension from Mageplaza here the link : https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-currency-formatter/  .

Than you can disable the decimal from magento admin panel ->stores->configuration-> Mageplaza Extensions.

This worked for me in magento 2.3.3 installation .

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

```
Override the below file and replace comma separator from the price

vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml
```

Answer (score -1):

this question is asked before, check solution provided here :

[How to change currency format in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115636/how-to-change-currency-format-in-magento-2)

Comment: In this code working correctly ??  this code suitable for my exacty questions ??

Comment: i have not tried it myself but you have to create custom module for that as per answered on reference post.

Answer (score -1):

overright

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.html`

to

```
app/design/[your module]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.html
```

and replace the content with:

```
<?php /** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount $block */ ?>

<span class="price-container <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAdjustmentCssClasses() ?>"
        <?= $block->getSchema() ? ' itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"' : '' ?>>
    <?php if ($block->getDisplayLabel()): ?>
        <span class="price-label"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayLabel() ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <span <?php if ($block->getPriceId()): ?> id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceId() ?>"<?php endif;?>
        <?= ($block->getPriceDisplayLabel()) ? 'data-label="' . $block->getPriceDisplayLabel() . $block->getPriceDisplayInclExclTaxes() . '"' : '' ?>
        data-price-amount="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayValue() ?>"
        data-price-type="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceType() ?>"
        class="price-wrapper <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceWrapperCss() ?>"
    ><?php $my_str1 =  /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()); 

    echo str_replace("٫", ".", $my_str1);
    ?>
    </span>
    <?php if ($block->hasAdjustmentsHtml()): ?>
        <?= $block->getAdjustmentsHtml() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($block->getSchema()): ?>
        <meta itemprop="price" content="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayValue() ?>" />
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayCurrencyCode() ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
</span>
```