# Magento2: How can remove comma from price?

Tags: magento2

I know my question may be duplicate of this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203312/how-to-remove-comma-separator-from-price-in-magento-2-1) but I have tried this and didn't get solution. I have edited core files of price with str replace but after page load it is again showing price with comma.

I have tired with Locale/xml file but price coming from js may be. Anyone have an idea for that please?

Answer (score 0):

Create custom module and override default file **Format.php**

Step1 : `app/code/Adamsmage/Custprice/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Locale\Format" type="Vendor\Currency\Model\Format" />
</config>
```

Step2 : `app/code/Adamsmage/Custprice/Model/Format.php`

```
<?php
namespace Adamsmage\Custprice\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Locale\Bundle\DataBundle;

class Format extends \Magento\Framework\Locale\Format
{
    private static $defaultNumberSet = 'latn';

    public function getPriceFormat($localeCode = null, $currencyCode = null)
    {
        $localeCode = $localeCode ?: $this->_localeResolver->getLocale();
        if ($currencyCode) {
            $currency = $this->currencyFactory->create()->load($currencyCode);
        } else {
            $currency = $this->_scopeResolver->getScope()->getCurrentCurrency();
        }

        $localeData = (new DataBundle())->get($localeCode);
        $defaultSet = $localeData['NumberElements']['default'] ?: self::$defaultNumberSet;

        $format = $localeData['NumberElements'][$defaultSet]['patterns']['currencyFormat']
            ?: ($localeData['NumberElements'][self::$defaultNumberSet]['patterns']['currencyFormat']
                ?: explode(';', $localeData['NumberPatterns'][1])[0]);

        //your main changes are gone here.....
        $decimalSymbol = '.';
        $groupSymbol = ',';

        $pos = strpos($format, ';');
        if ($pos !== false) {
            $format = substr($format, 0, $pos);
        }
        $format = preg_replace("/[^0\#\.,]/", "", $format);
        $totalPrecision = 0;
        $decimalPoint = strpos($format, '.');
        if ($decimalPoint !== false) {
            $totalPrecision = strlen($format) - (strrpos($format, '.') + 1);
        } else {
            $decimalPoint = strlen($format);
        }
        $requiredPrecision = $totalPrecision;
        $t = substr($format, $decimalPoint);
        $pos = strpos($t, '#');
        if ($pos !== false) {
            $requiredPrecision = strlen($t) - $pos - $totalPrecision;
        }

        if (strrpos($format, ',') !== false) {
            $group = $decimalPoint - strrpos($format, ',') - 1;
        } else {
            $group = strrpos($format, '.');
        }
        $integerRequired = strpos($format, '.') - strpos($format, '0');

        $result = [
            //TODO: change interface
            'pattern' => $currency->getOutputFormat(),
            'precision' => $totalPrecision,
            'requiredPrecision' => $requiredPrecision,
            'decimalSymbol' => $decimalSymbol,
            'groupSymbol' => $groupSymbol,
            'groupLength' => $group,
            'integerRequired' => $integerRequired,
        ];       
        return $result;
    }
}
```

I hope its work for you.

Answer (score 0):

to remove decimals , you just need to install the free module Currency Formatter Extension from Mageplaza here the link : https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-currency-formatter/  .

Than you can disable the decimal from magento admin panel ->stores->configuration-> Mageplaza Extensions.

This worked for me in magento 2.3.3 installation .

Best regards