# Magento2 display price in 2.5 lac, 3.5 crore, 25 lac etc

Tags: magento2, price, product-view, render

How to display product price on listing page, product detail page in numbers & letters combination.

**For example  2.5 lac, 3 crore etc**.
In PHP I can get price using following logic, but how to implement it in Magento2?

```
<?php

namespace Dcw\Search\Helper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
class Price extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper {




    public function __construct(
    Context $context
    , array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return type
     */
    public function getPrice($num) {

    $ext="";//thousand,lac, crore
    $number_of_digits = $this->count_digit($num); //this is call :)
      if($number_of_digits>3)
        {
            if($number_of_digits%2!=0)
              $divider=$this->divider($number_of_digits-1);
            else
               $divider=$this->divider($number_of_digits);
        }
        else
         $divider=1;

        $fraction=$num/$divider;
        $fraction=number_format($fraction,2);
        if($number_of_digits==4 ||$number_of_digits==5)
         $ext="k";
        if($number_of_digits==6 ||$number_of_digits==7)
          $ext="Lac";
        if($number_of_digits==8 ||$number_of_digits==9)
            $ext="Cr";

        return $fraction." ".$ext;
    }


protected function count_digit($number) {
  return strlen($number);
}

protected function divider($number_of_digits) {
    $tens="1";

  if($number_of_digits>8)
    return 10000000;

  while(($number_of_digits-1)>0)
  {
    $tens.="0";
    $number_of_digits--;
  }
  return $tens;
}



}
```

Answer (score 4):

> **app/code/Package/Modulename/etc/di.xml**
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
>     <preference for="Magento\Framework\Locale\Format" type="Vendor\Currency\Model\Format" />
> </config>
> ```
>
> **app/code/Package/Modulename/Model/Format.php**
>
> ```
> <?php
> namespace Package\Modulename\Model;
>
> use Magento\Framework\Locale\Bundle\DataBundle;
>
> class Format extends \Magento\Framework\Locale\Format
> {
>     private static $defaultNumberSet = 'latn';
>
>     public function getPriceFormat($localeCode = null, $currencyCode = null)
>     {
>         $localeCode = $localeCode ?: $this->_localeResolver->getLocale();
>         if ($currencyCode) {
>             $currency = $this->currencyFactory->create()->load($currencyCode);
>         } else {
>             $currency = $this->_scopeResolver->getScope()->getCurrentCurrency();
>         }
>
>         $localeData = (new DataBundle())->get($localeCode);
>         $defaultSet = $localeData['NumberElements']['default'] ?: self::$defaultNumberSet;
>
>         $format = $localeData['NumberElements'][$defaultSet]['patterns']['currencyFormat']
>             ?: ($localeData['NumberElements'][self::$defaultNumberSet]['patterns']['currencyFormat']
>                 ?: explode(';', $localeData['NumberPatterns'][1])[0]);
>
>         //your main changes are gone here.....
>         $decimalSymbol = '.';
>         $groupSymbol = ',';
>
>         $pos = strpos($format, ';');
>         if ($pos !== false) {
>             $format = substr($format, 0, $pos);
>         }
>         $format = preg_replace("/[^0\#\.,]/", "", $format);
>         $totalPrecision = 0;
>         $decimalPoint = strpos($format, '.');
>         if ($decimalPoint !== false) {
>             $totalPrecision = strlen($format) - (strrpos($format, '.') + 1);
>         } else {
>             $decimalPoint = strlen($format);
>         }
>         $requiredPrecision = $totalPrecision;
>         $t = substr($format, $decimalPoint);
>         $pos = strpos($t, '#');
>         if ($pos !== false) {
>             $requiredPrecision = strlen($t) - $pos - $totalPrecision;
>         }
>
>         if (strrpos($format, ',') !== false) {
>             $group = $decimalPoint - strrpos($format, ',') - 1;
>         } else {
>             $group = strrpos($format, '.');
>         }
>         $integerRequired = strpos($format, '.') - strpos($format, '0');
>
>         $result = [
>             //TODO: change interface
>             'pattern' => $currency->getOutputFormat(),
>             'precision' => $totalPrecision,
>             'requiredPrecision' => $requiredPrecision,
>             'decimalSymbol' => $decimalSymbol,
>             'groupSymbol' => $groupSymbol,
>             'groupLength' => $group,
>             'integerRequired' => $integerRequired,
>         ];       
>         return $result;
>     }
> }
> ```

Source:

- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/152499/69

Obviously the currency/locale would need to be changed but your question is how to approach implementing the currency format.

Also, a perhaps a more elegant GST currency converter method:

```
function formatCurrency(number) {
    var numberStr = number.toString();
    var thousandsMatcher = /(\d+)(\d{3})$/;
    var thousandsAndRest = thousandsMatcher.exec(numberStr);
    if (!thousandsAndRest) return numberStr;
    return thousandsAndRest[1].replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + "," + thousandsAndRest[2];
}
```

- https://gist.github.com/anagri/6650737

Lastly, there's this open source currency-format module that may offer some insight or a direct solution to the problem.

- https://github.com/mage2pro/currency-format

Comment: Also worth looking into `Zend_Locale` https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.locale.functions.html