# Magento2: How to Change the price format?

Tags: magento2, price, format

I need to change the price format from "10,00" to "10,-". I have tried to find info, but all that I saw is: How to change "," to "." like this

[How to change currency format in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115636/how-to-change-currency-format-in-magento-2)

(and btw it's not working for product page). And no info on how to add few symbols after price. I know how to do it by jS but it's the last what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use extension attributes for /vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/PriceCurrencyInterface.php

in interface PriceCurrencyInterface

```
const DEFAULT_PRECISION = 2;
```

set value to 0

You cannot overwrite interfaces in Magento 2.

More about extensions attributes https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html

and last if you need ,-  like this 10,-

just add

```
span.price:after {
    content: ',-';
}
```

Comment: Thx for reply, i did all what is here http://aasim.kodefolks.com/magento-2/change-price-format-magento-2/ and on product page i still can see price like "10,00" but should be like "10". But it's not my main question, so there is no way to add somewhere few symbols? Cause i don't need to change interface, i need to add. For example there are some function where all combines and show on front end ?

Comment: I update my answer, by adding  span.price:after {
    content: ',-';
} change this that feet on your theme.

Comment: Thx for reply, i forgot about it. Though i still have problem with product page, but i think i must make other question.