# Magento2:Format price

Tags: magento2, price, format

I have a website where currency is displayed in the format xx,xx CHF. I want to it to the format CHF xx.xx

I got the solution to position the currency symbol by refering the below link.

https://magecomp.com/blog/change-currency-symbol-position-left-right-magento-2/

Added the below files

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="currency_display_options_forming">
        <observer name="vendor_extension_change_currency_position" instance="Vendor\Module\Model\Observer\Changecurrencyposition" />
    </event>
</config>
```

app\code\Vendor\Module\Model\Observer\Changecurrencyposition

```
<?php        
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Observer;    
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;    
class Changecurrencyposition implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {    
        $currencyOptions = $observer->getEvent()->getCurrencyOptions();    
        $currencyOptions->setData('position', \Magento\Framework\Currency::LEFT);  
        return $this;
    }    
}
```

This worked for me to change the position of price symbol.

Now I need to change the price separator from ',' to '.' 
I found a solution [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115636/how-to-change-currency-format-in-magento-2)

Added the below files to change the price formatter.
app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Locale\Format" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Format" />
</config>
```

app\code\Vendor\Module\Model\Format.php

```
    <?php
    namespace venor\Module\Model;

    use Magento\Framework\Locale\Bundle\DataBundle;

class Format extends \Magento\Framework\Locale\Format
{
    private static $defaultNumberSet = 'latn';

    public function getPriceFormat($localeCode = null, $currencyCode = null)
    {
        $localeCode = $localeCode ?: $this->_localeResolver->getLocale();
        if ($currencyCode) {
            $currency = $this->currencyFactory->create()->load($currencyCode);
        } else {
            $currency = $this->_scopeResolver->getScope()->getCurrentCurrency();
        }

        $localeData = (new DataBundle())->get($localeCode);
        $defaultSet = $localeData['NumberElements']['default'] ?: self::$defaultNumberSet;

        $format = $localeData['NumberElements'][$defaultSet]['patterns']['currencyFormat']
            ?: ($localeData['NumberElements'][self::$defaultNumberSet]['patterns']['currencyFormat']
                ?: explode(';', $localeData['NumberPatterns'][1])[0]);

        //your main changes are gone here.....
        $decimalSymbol = '.';
        $groupSymbol = ',';

        $pos = strpos($format, ';');
        if ($pos !== false) {
            $format = substr($format, 0, $pos);
        }
        $format = preg_replace("/[^0\#\.,]/", "", $format);
        $totalPrecision = 0;
        $decimalPoint = strpos($format, '.');
        if ($decimalPoint !== false) {
            $totalPrecision = strlen($format) - (strrpos($format, '.') + 1);
        } else {
            $decimalPoint = strlen($format);
        }
        $requiredPrecision = $totalPrecision;
        $t = substr($format, $decimalPoint);
        $pos = strpos($t, '#');
        if ($pos !== false) {
            $requiredPrecision = strlen($t) - $pos - $totalPrecision;
        }

        if (strrpos($format, ',') !== false) {
            $group = $decimalPoint - strrpos($format, ',') - 1;
        } else {
            $group = strrpos($format, '.');
        }
        $integerRequired = strpos($format, '.') - strpos($format, '0');

        $result = [
            //TODO: change interface
            'pattern' => $currency->getOutputFormat(),
            'precision' => $totalPrecision,
            'requiredPrecision' => $requiredPrecision,
            'decimalSymbol' => $decimalSymbol,
            'groupSymbol' => $groupSymbol,
            'groupLength' => $group,
            'integerRequired' => $integerRequired,
        ];       
        return $result;
        }
    }
```

But it is working only in view page not in listingpage, minicart etc

Can anyone provide a solution for this??

Comment: Share your code for better understand.

Comment: @ChiragPatel I have added the code. Can you please provide a solution?