# Price of product displayed incorrectly in Arabic view

Tags: magento2, pricing, arabic

While switching to Arabic view, price of the product is displayed as described :
150.00 is being displayed as 1,50.00.

Please anyone help in resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

Create just simple module and overrider default *Format.php** file,

[How to change currency format in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115636/how-to-change-currency-format-in-magento-2)