# how to remove decimal from price

Tags: price, magento2.3.1

in magento 2.3.1 want to remove decimal place from price from whole website.

like price is 45355,00 than it is showing like 45.355,00 on category page and catalog page, cart page, checkout page everywhere.

So i want only 45355,00 is there any solution for it?

Comment: Hope this helps you. Below a reference link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663883/magento-delete-the-thousand-separator-in-price

Comment: it is not for magento 2

Comment: please try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115636/how-to-change-currency-format-in-magento-2

Answer (score 1):

Try this extension it's working good for me.
https://github.com/lillik/magento2-price-decimal

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Jimit Bhavsar works very well.

Comment: You can always Vote Up or comment if the posted answer is useful by the user instead of posting another answer without a solution.