# Magento 2 : Product Price Translated in multi website

Tags: magento2, price, upgrade, currency

I have 2 language website like Arabic and English in which currency format is not matching in both store.If product has price 299 $ then it have show Like this because of Arabic language.

**AR Store : ٢٩٩٫٠٠ SAR**

**En Store : $ 299**

But I need to show like

**AR Store : 299 SAR**

**En Store : $ 299**

Comment: check this answer :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115636/how-to-change-currency-format-in-magento-2 Thanks,

Comment: Check this answer :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115636/how-to-change-currency-format-in-magento-2 Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing same issue before. We can resolve this translation issue by do changes in following two files:-

1] Create plugin for change currency position as following:

**registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Trek_Repositionprice',
    __DIR__
);
```

**etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Trek_Repositionprice" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

**etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Directory\Model\Currency">
        <plugin name="change_currency_position"
            type="Trek\Repositionprice\Plugin\ChangeCurrencyPosition"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Plugin/ChangeCurrencyPosition.php**

```
<?php

namespace Trek\Repositionprice\Plugin;

class ChangeCurrencyPosition
{
    /**
     * Change currency position
     *
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $subject
     * @param float $price
     * @param array $options
     * @return array|array[]
     */
    public function beforeFormatTxt(
        \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $subject,
        $price,
        $options = []
    ) {
        $options['position'] = 16; // 16 is for Right position, 8 is for Standard position and 32 is for Left position
        return [$price,$options];
    }
}
```

2] If still after create above plugin whole price coverted in wrong format then we need to override `price-utils.js` file as below:-

- Just copy `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-utils.js` file into your custom theme directory for ex `app/design/frontend/Namespace/Themename/Magento_Catalog/web/js/price-utils.js`
- Here `window.LOCALE` condition which converts whole price into particular locale language

[image]

After removed `window.LOCALE`condition price translation working proper.

[image]

Hope it works. Thanks.