# Magento 2 : how to remove Product Price getting Translated?

Tags: translate, magento2.4.6, product-prices, multi-language, arabic

I have a multilanguage site (Arabic and English) which is upgraded from 2.4.3 to 2.4.6-p3. Now the product price is translated in Arabic store view (eg: if the price is 399.5  then it is like ٣٩٩٫٥٠  KD). How can I remove this translation? In previous version it was working fine.

Also, I need the price format as follows.

**AR Store :**

[image]

**En Store :**  299.050 KD

Now it is like

**AR Store :**
[image]

**En Store :** KD 299.05

Please help me to do the formatting also

Comment: Please follow this link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/360607/magento-2-product-price-translated-in-multi-website

Comment: @GrazittiDev Tried the same. But it is not working